# Update SQL syntax error

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program which requires updating user data in an ACCESS Db.
While running the code I get above error. my update statement is..

```
con.Open();
string update = "UPDATE userdata SET full_name='"+name+
                "', user_type ='" + user_type +
                "', gender = '" + gender +
                "', password='"+password+
                "', tel_number='"+tel_number+
                "', blood_type ='"+blood_type+
                "'WHERE user_id='" + user_id + "'";                                   

cmd = new OleDbCommand(update, con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close();
MessageBox.Show("Userdata successfully updated!");
```

Comment: by the way the update fields are in exact order of Access Db

Comment: Replace this `'WHERE` with `' WHERE`; mean you need a space here;

Comment: you really should be using parameters

Comment: thanks guys. yeah I added parameters. turns out 'password' is a reserved word in ms access. changing to [password ] worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you should frame your query. Also it's good practice to wrap your `oledbCommand` inside using statement

```
  con.Open();
  using (OleDbCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
  {
   cmd.CommandText="UPDATE userdata
                  SET full_name= @full_name, user_type= @user_type, 
                      gender= @gender,password= @password, tel_number= @tel_number, 
                      blood_type= @blood_type Where user_id= @user_id;


       // add named parameters
       cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
       {
           new OleDbParameter("@user_type", user_type ),
           new OleDbParameter("@gender", gender),
           new OleDbParameter("@password", password),
           ...
       };

       // execute
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL.... 'WHERE user_id='"
```

Try changing it to `' WHERE user_id='"`

Notice there is a space there.